# Get default left and top position of element after rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I am using jQuery draggable event in my project, while dragging I get the correct left and top position of the element if the element is not rotated using,

```
jQuery(element).position().top
jQuery(element).position().left
```

Using the below code,

```
  jQuery(element).draggable({
                drag: function(){
                    positionUpdate();
                },
                stop: function(){
                    positionUpdate();
                }
            });

function positionUpdate(){
    var left = jQuery(element).position().left;
    var top = jQuery(element).position().top;
    console.log('left - '+ left);
    console.log('top - '+ top);
}
```

So something like gets printed,

```
left - 20
top - 50
```

But if the element is rotated keeping the same position then something like the below gets printed,

```
left - 25.3456
top  - 40.54545
```

Please help me with this, I want the original value (20,50) without rotation degrees to get printed while dragging the rotated element,

Thanks and Regards,

Neha

Answer (score 0):

Try http://jqueryrotate.com/

Code Example

```
$("#img").rotate({bind:{
  click: function(){
    $(this).rotate({
      angle: 0,
      center: ["50%", "100%"],
      animateTo:180
      })
    }
  }
});
```

This way you can pin your center and it doesn't allow it to change after your drag call.

Comment: I want the left and top pixel values, the element should be allowed to rotate